# using ConfigurationProperties in test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have an ApplicationProperties that i use it in my service. When i mock the rest template in my test to test that service it results in `java.lang.NullPointerException`, when i replace `applicationProperties.getBebusiness().getEndPointProvider()` with the url, the test passes

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class ApplicationProperties { ...
}


@Service
public class ProviderServiceImpl implements ProviderService {

    private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ProviderServiceImpl(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties, RestTemplate restTemplater) {
        this.applicationProperties = applicationProperties;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public List <ProviderDTO> getAllProviderFromBebusiness() {
        final List <ProviderDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();
        final ResponseEntity <String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(
            applicationProperties.getBebusiness().getEndPointProvider() + "&page=0&size=" + Integer.MAX_VALUE, String.class);
        if (responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue() == 200) {}
        return result;
    }

}


public class ProviderServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @InjectMocks
    private ProviderServiceImpl providerService;

    @Test
    public void givenMockingIsDoneByMockito_whenGetIsCalled_shouldReturnMockedObject() {
        String provider = providerInit.buildProviderDTOWithIdFromBebusiness();
        ResponseEntity <String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity <String> (provider, HttpStatus.OK);
        when(restTemplate.getForEntity(anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(Class.class)))
            .thenReturn(responseEntity);
        List<ProviderDTO> result = providerService.getAllProviderFromBebusiness();
        assertEquals(200, responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to create a separate application.properties(/.yml) file in test resource folder with test configurations.

Comment: @Lipu i have the application.yml file in the test resource folder

Comment: I don't see that you are using @SpringBootTest annotation in your test class. This is required to load the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your spring beans are not instantiated. You have to annotate your test class to tell spring it has to initialize its context. Try use @SpringBootTest annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` annotation or if you don't want to run Spring Boot context then just mock your configuration class as following:

```
    @BeforeEach // @Before if you're using JUnit4
    void setUp() {
      Bebusiness bebusiness = mock(Bebusiness.class);
      when(applicationProperties.getBebusiness()).thenReturn(bebusiness);
      when(bebusiness.getEndPointProvider()).thenReturn("http://localhost:8080");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/other-location.properties")
```

Or

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.datasource.max-active=30,
spring.datasource.initial-size=5")
```

This is a exemple : https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/test-property-source-with-inlined-properties.html